# how to do update in table in spark-SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I want to update one row in table which is present in spark-SQL, so how can i do it.
e.g My original query is ,
Update from student set marks = 56 where id =1;

How to do this in spark-SQL? As update is not supported in spark-SQL.
please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL dataframes, at their core, are RDDs and these are immutable meaning you cant change (update) them. However, you generate new Spark SQL Dataframe by applying User Defined Function (UDF) on the original Dataframe something like this:

```
val my_udf=udf{(given_id:Int, given_marks:Int)=> if(given_id==5) 5 else given_marks}

val new_df= original_df.select(id,my_udf(id,marks))
```